# The operation couldn’t be completed with writeToFile

Tags: objective-c, nsfilemanager

I have this code who create a text file inside my directory in iphone:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
    (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/file.txt",
                          documentsDirectory];

    NSString *content = @"my first text";

    NSError *error;

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileName] == NO) {

    [content writeToFile:fileName
              atomically:YES
                encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy
                   error:&error];

    }else{

        [content writeToFile:fileName
                  atomically:YES
                    encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy
                       error:&error];

    }
```

the code was working perfectly until at a certain time it does not work anymore, and is returning the following error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=517 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (Cocoa error 517.)" UserInfo=0x8c852b0
>   {NSFilePath=/Users/williamlima/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/7.1/Applications/B5781B9E-3915-4656-83D4-5E0FB6486567/Documents/file.txt,
>   NSStringEncoding=1}

How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

You can try with UTF8Encoding

```
[content writeToFile:fileName
              atomically:YES
                encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding
                   error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0):

my two cents:

Ozgur fix works in Mojave 10.4 using objC in Xcode 10, solving the error.